# setNumberFormats not working properly for percentages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google spreadsheet in which I want to copy values from one range into another range using a script. Copying the values isn't hard; I just use `range.setValues(valuesToCopy)`. I also want to copy the formatting of the original range over to the new range. The problem is that whenever a percentage occurs, it doesn't apply the format correctly and always ends up off by a factor of 100. For example, if the original cell contains a value of 0.5545, the formatting of the cell turns it into 55.45% (which is what I want); however, when I copy the values to another range and apply the formatting with `setNumberFormats()`, it turns it into 0.5545%. How can I fix this?

EDIT: So, after a bit more fiddling around, it appears that my script properly copies the formatting over the first time, but on subsequent executions of the script, the formatting for the percentages gets messed up, as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

To copy values, use the [`.copyTo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo%28Range%29) method, and the format is preserved by default. For example,

```
rangeFrom.copyTo(rangeTo)
```